# Can I say: "He is carving way into there?"

Tags: grammaticality

I have already mentioned the place and I don't want repeat it; so I wonder if I can use "there" instead to refer to the same place.

Sentence:

> The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym, and the one
>   who is still carving his way into "there" (The back of the gym)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend the verb *carving* to mean? I'm not sure it fits here.  You also need to finish the thought.  The construction is:  The difference between X and Y is D.  Your sentence does not ever state what D is.  E.g., *The difference between men and boys is the price of their toys.*  *The difference between oil and water is that water in not flammable*.

Comment: In this instance you probably don't need to use anything; the reference can be implicit:  *The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym and the one who is still [carving?] his way in is that the guys in the back have been coming here for years.*

Comment: Jim: Thank you the answer. I am aware the thought is incomplete. That is actually only part the sentence. I am using "carve" as in "carve one's way into success."

Comment: Jim: Do you think this works: The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym and the one who is still carving his way into where they are is that the guys at the back have been coming here for years.

Comment: I've never heard *carving your way to success.* I suppose I'd recognize the meaning from context, but it's not a standard phrase.  I think a much better phrase might be something like:  *The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym and the one who is still trying to work up to their level, is about 5 years.*

Comment: @asef: Per Jim's comments, I think you should be careful about "creative" figurative usages like this. When you have some additional support for the "unusual" usage (such as [Dan carving his way into a meaty role](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Dan+carving+his+way+into+a+meaty+role.-a066440013)), it can work really well. In your case, though, the reader could be left with the suspicion you might simply be literally translating a figurative usage that's familiar to you (even cliched) in your native language, but sounds rather odd to Anglophones.

Comment: @Jim, FumbleFingers: To aid the OP, I think the OP is trying to use *carving* figuratively to express the effort of bodybuilders with what sculptures do. I don't know if this works: *The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym and the one who is still carving himself out to be just like those guys is ...* -- Or maybe *carving himself into the perfect body of those guys is ...*

Comment: @Jim: I've heard of _carving_ being used this way, roughly. The _Sacromento Bee_ mentioned how Barry Bonds was **carving his way into the record books**. I found another quote online that talked about someone "carving his way" into a leadership role. One book reads: "Al Jolson carved his way into movie history by becoming the first man to speak on the screen." OED mentions a figurative use of _carve_: "To help or serve at one's own discretion, to do at one's pleasure, indulge oneself; To apportion at discretion, to assign as one's portion or lot, to take at one's pleasure"

Comment: @J.R.- Interesting.  I wonder what percent of the population is familiar with it?  I'd be fine with it in any number of surfing, skiing, skateboarding -type situations, or FF's meaty role, I don't see Al Jolson doing any carving. I expect *carving* to be somehow used *as with a knife.*  Oh, well, live and learn.

Comment: @Jim - I think "chiseled" might be a better word for the O.P.; at least there would be a slight pun: _There is a difference between the guys who work out at the back of the gym, and the ones who are still trying to chisel their way back there._

Comment: @Jim While I was researching this I ran into a lot of *carving his way*s that were literal - Jim Bowie, Rodin, Borglum. And in almost every case the writer made a point of saying that "X **literally** carved his way into Y".

Comment: @StoneyB- Yes, those are quite good.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your comment has one big assumption, one that is untrue. What do you mean "in your case"? If I am using a figurative expression right, then who cares what "my case" is. "To carve one's way into something/being something" is a very common expression. I think, honestly, that some native speakers make the mistake that if 'they' are not familiar with a certain phrase, then it somehow does not exit. On what grounds did you assume of my lack of the so-called "additional support"? I ask this with all due respect.

Comment: Asef, we're a learners' site, and very few of our questioners have the command of English you do--which means that most of them are incapable of finding the "additional support". So 99% of the time we're justified in assuming that if the background research doesn't show up in the question, it wasn't performed. On the other hand, a major difference between ELL and other SE sites is that they simply close a question (like yours) which doesn't include the research. That rarely happens here; instead, we ask for it.

Comment: ... As for your other point: we're an international site; it is not at all uncommon for an expression which is very common on one side of the Atlantic or Pacific to sound odd and alien on the other side. There are **lots** of Englishes out there, not just one.

Comment: StoneyB: Duly noted.

Comment: Asef, you should note that almost all (valid) instances of figurative *carving one's way in* (and J.R.'s *chiseling*) will imply *getting there **in the face of active opposition/resistance** [from the current incumbents]*. I really don't think it works very well when the context is largely "non-competitive" (in respect of the relationship between the new guys and the seasoned pros at a gym).

Comment: @Fumble - There are two ways to look at it, I suppose. If it's a gym where the seasoned vets aren't so welcoming to those coming in fresh off their New Year's resolutions, if they are a clique who will stare down a newcomer in an intimidating manner for just thinking about coming back to their corner to grab a dumbbell, then the word "carve" might be just to word to convey that resistance. Several people read this sentence and thought, "Hmmm... _carve_ doesn't seem to be right word here." I read the sentence and thought, "Wow, that sounds like one tough gym..."

Answer (score 2):

To *carve a way* or *path*, or *one's way* or *path* is a fairly common metaphor for achieving a goal through protracted effort, as if you were hacking out a path through a jungle.

But when I read this question my first reaction was the same as FumbleFingers': that these phrases are used with *to* but not with *into*. Indeed, I was prepared to suggest that you were confusing the notion of *carving a way* with that of *carving out a place*.

But I thought I'd better check my facts; and I found to my surprise, that *carved his way **into***, though much less used than *carved his way **to***, has had a respectable presence since the 1880s. Here are some examples, from Google Books:

> Al Jolson was already a vaudeville topliner when he carved his way into movie history ...
>
> Among Rutherford's earlier biographers only one seems to have realised that the young man carved his way into McGill—nearly all the others see the picture as McGill picking the brightest young man from J.J.'s stable.
>
> He had reached the age when a man, having carved his way into the esteem of his fellows, may be expected to settle back as a dignitary in some inner office ...

The only issue, then, is whether you can idiomatically use *there* as the object of the preposition *into*—which is of course what you actually ask!

My answer is a very qualified Yes. By and large we do not speak of any sort of movement ***into*** there. I can give you no reason; but we prefer ***in*** there, even when there is some sort of entry or penetration for which *into* would otherwise be proper.

But if you turn *there* into a **name** rather than just a pronoun representing a previously identified place, I think it will fly. That in fact is what is suggested by your quotation marks around the word. However, those quotation marks by themselves are not enough; what you have to do is establish “there” as a name *before* you say *carving his way into “there”*. Something like this:

> The front is wide open. Anybody who pays his membership fee can work out in the front part of the gym. But the back is something else. The back isn’t posted, there are no signs or barriers. The back doesn’t have a special name; on the contrary, it’s never even spoken about; if you absolutely have to refer to it it’s just “there”, with a little pause in front of it. Because “there” is the Grail Castle. It’s the Holy of Holies. “There” is where the pros work out, the competitors, the fanatics. There’s a huge difference between the heroic shadows working out at the back and the wannabe trying to carve his way into "there".

Comment: Many, many thanks for the conscientious answer. Many more for doing diligence to find whether it is "to" or "into." It frankly drives me nuts that some people assume a phrase, used by a non-native speaker, must be wrong if they have not heard it. I REALLY appreciate the quotations!!

Answer (score 2):

> The difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym, and the one who is still carving his way into there.

The sentence has a few problems:

- It's not really a complete sentence (it has a subject but no predicate).
- I don't care for the way the first part of the sentence refers to the plural, while the second half refers to the singular.

So, I'll start with a modification to your original:

> There's a difference between the guys working out at the back of the gym and the ones who are still carving their way back there.

I prefer "back there" to "into there," because that seems to fit the context better. However, "into there" might work better in a different context:

> There's a difference between those who have had a chance to fly in the cockpit of a glider, and the ones who are still hoping for a chance to get into there.

But, yes, "there" can be used to refer to a place previously mentioned in a sentence.

<sub>There's also an issue about the word *carve* in this context, but that's been discussed in the comments, so I won't address it here.</sub>

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful, and addresses EXACTLY what I needed. I would have voted ten times if I could.